# iOS Swift: Sound not playing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio

In my iOS Swift application, and i am trying to play sound on click of a button.

```
func playSound()
    {
        var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
        let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("doorbell", withExtension: "mp3")
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.play()
}
```

I am running the application in iOS iPhone Simulator.
I have doorbell.mp3 added to the application. In debug mode i can see that soundURL has a value and it is not nil.

There are no errors, but the sound does not play.

Comment: Check your volume on you computer

Comment: Arbitur> The volume is fine, i am able to play the doorbell.mp3 file outside the application. So either i have the code wrong or something to do with Simulator....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to move the declaration of your audioPlayer out of your method. Try like this:

**Swift 3 or later**

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playSound() throws {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "doorbell", withExtension: "mp3")!
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

---

```
do { 
    try playSound() 
} catch { 
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Leo> Yes that worked...thanks, it would be great if you could add a small explanation too as to why this works when moved out.

Comment: If you declare your player inside the method it would go out of existence as soon as it finishes executing your method.